# Insomnia base64 decode a response body attribute and print

Tags: base64, insomnia

I would like to retrieve one of my response body attributes, base64 decode and see in json formatted way.Is it possible to view the data in this format right with rest api execution.

Comment: do you want to use a self designed plugin?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Can you point out to any docs which talks about self designed plugins in insomnia ?